# Description of free Lie algebra in Weibel's book

Tags: category-theory, lie-algebras, free-lie-algebra

In Exercise 7.3.2 in Weibel's book *An Introduction to Homological algebra* the following description of the free Lie algebra over some $k$-module $M$ is given (where $k$ is any commutative ring):

First, consider the tensor algebra $T(M)$. Take the underlying Lie algebra $\mathrm{Lie}(T(M))$, i.e. $[x,y] = xy-yx$. Then, consider the Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak{f}(M) \subseteq \mathrm{Lie}(T(M))$ generated by $M$. The claim is that $\mathfrak{f}(M)$ is the free Lie algebra on $M$, i.e. that every $k$-linear map $f : M \to \mathfrak{g}|_k$ into the underlying $k$-module of some Lie algebra extends uniquely to a Lie algebra map $\overline{f} : \mathfrak{f}(M) \to \mathfrak{g}$.

Well, uniqueness is clear, since $M$ generates $\mathfrak{f}(M)$. Specifically, we have to map $[x_1,[x_2,[\dotsc[x_{n-1},x_n]\dotsc]]]$ to $[f(x_1),[f(x_2),[\dotsc[f(x_{n-1}),f(x_n)]\dotsc]]]$ and $\mathfrak{f}(M)|_k$ is generated by these elements. But I am not able to show existence, i.e. that this is well-defined.

By naturality, we may assume $M=\mathfrak{g}|_k$ and $f=\mathrm{id}$. The simplest special case for well-definedness is the following: If $[x,y]=0$ in $\mathfrak{f}(M)$, i.e. $x \otimes y = y \otimes x$ in $M^{\otimes 2}$, why do we have $[x,y]=0$ in $\mathfrak{g}$? This holds when $k$ is a field, because then $x \otimes y = y \otimes x$ implies $x \in \langle y \rangle$ and $[x,y]=0$ follows from $[y,y]=0$. If $k$ is arbitrary, I can only see $2 \cdot [x,y]=0$ (in fact, $[x,y]=[y,x]$ because the Lie bracket is bilinear, and $[y,x]=-[x,y]$ holds in general). So if $2 \in k^{\times}$, it would follow again that $[x,y]=0$, but otherwise it is not clear.

Shouldn't it be possible to construct a counterexample? It doesn't appear in the [Errata](http://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/602/bookerrors.pdf), though. Is the description true, at least, when $k$ is a field? This should be connected to the PBW-theorem.

Comment: Perhaps you are supposed to use the PBW theorem to embed $\mathfrak{g}$ in its universal enveloping algebra.

Comment: I don't believe this description is correct unless PBW holds over $k$. But this is in some sense not surprising; aren't there all sorts of mistakes in Weibel?

Comment: Lie algebras don't work (that way) for characteristic $2$!

Comment: I am also pretty sure that the description is wrong ... but I would appreciate a detailed answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: Serre shows in Lie Algebras and Lie Groups, Theorem 4.2 (2) that $\mathfrak f(M) \to T(M)$ is an isomorphism of the free lie algebra on $M$ onto the lie subalgebra of $T(M)$ generated by $M$. There, he also assumes that $k$ is an arbitrary commutative ring with unit (though $M$ should be a free $k$-module). I hope this might help.

Comment: There are two cases in which Weibel's claim definitely holds: **(1)** the case when $1,2,3,\ldots$ are invertible in $k$, and **(2)** the case when $M$ is a free $k$-module. In case **(2)**, the claim follows from what @user218931 wrote (or, alternatively, from Remark 6.42 in http://arxiv.org/src/1409.8356v3/anc/HopfComb-v54-with-solutions.pdf ). In case **(1)**, it follows from Proposition 7.2.8 in Volume I of Benoit Fresse's "Homotopy of Operads" book ( http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/ ).

Comment: I don't know whether Weibel's claim holds in full generality; I would suspect that it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you. Why not writing an answer? :) The cases, in which it holds, are also of interest.

Comment: Well, I prefer to see the general case as the actual question :)

Comment: I've now answered that question too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1.** In the general case, Weibel's Exercise 7.3.2 is wrong: The Lie
subalgebra $\mathfrak{f}\left(  M\right)  $ of $\operatorname{Lie}\left(
T\left(  M\right)  \right)  $ is not always a free Lie algebra on $M$ (at
least not if the inclusion of $M$ into it is considered as the canonical map).
To see why not, we shall use the counterexample constructed in §5 of

[P.M. Cohn, *A remark on the Birkhoff-Witt theorem*, J. London Math. Soc. 38
(1963), pp. 197--203](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s1-38/1/197.full.pdf).

The counterexample goes as follows (I have kept the notation but slightly
modified the definitions): Let $p$ be a prime, and let $K$ be a field of
characteristic $p$. Let $k$ be the commutative ring $k\left[  \alpha
,\beta,\gamma\ \mid\ \alpha^{p}=0,\ \beta^{p}=0,\ \gamma^{p}=0\right]  $. Let
$M$ be the $k$-module given by generators $x,y,z$ and relations $\alpha
x=\beta y+\gamma z$. Let $L$ be the free Lie algebra of $M$ (defined in the
usual way -- i.e., as a quotient of a free magmatic algebra, not using
$T\left(  M\right)  $). Then, the universal enveloping algebra $U\left(
L\right)  $ of $L$ is canonically isomorphic to the tensor algebra $T\left(
M\right)  $ (see, e.g., [math.stackexchange #1030593](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030593/the-universal-enveloping-algebra-of-free-lie-algebra-is-the-tensor-algebra-on-th)). Cohn defines a
certain element $\Lambda_{p}\left(  \beta y,\gamma z\right)  $ of $L$ and
shows that $\Lambda_{p}\left(  \beta y,\gamma z\right)  =0$ in $U\left(
L\right)  $. Thus, $\Lambda_{p}\left(  \beta y,\gamma z\right)  =0$ in
$\mathfrak{f}\left(  M\right)  $ (since $\mathfrak{f}\left(  M\right)
\subseteq\operatorname*{Lie}\left(  T\left(  M\right)  \right)  \cong
\operatorname*{Lie}\left(  U\left(  L\right)  \right)  $).

On the other hand, Cohn claims that $\Lambda_{p}\left(  \beta y,\gamma
z\right)  \neq0$ in $L$. It is not clear if this latter claim has ever been
proven, but at least it can easily be checked by computation for $p=2$ and for
$p=3$, which means that at least for these primes $p$ we have a counterexample
(see [mathoverflow #61981](https://mathoverflow.net/a/61981/) and the comments beneath it for a discussion).
Anyway, we just want one counterexample, so $p=2$ is perfectly enough for us.
Combining the fact that $\Lambda_{p}\left(  \beta y,\gamma z\right)  \neq0$ in
$L$ with the fact that $\Lambda_{p}\left(  \beta y,\gamma z\right)  =0$ in
$\mathfrak{f}\left(  M\right)  $, we see that $\mathfrak{f}\left(  M\right)  $
cannot be a free Lie algebra on $M$ (because if it were, then there would be a
Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{f}\left(  M\right)  \rightarrow L$ sending
$x,y,z$ to $x,y,z$).

**2.** However, in many cases, Weibel's Exercise 7.3.2 is correct. One such
case is when $M$ is a free $k$-module. In this case, the Exercise follows from
Remark 6.42 in [Darij Grinberg and Victor Reiner, *Hopf Algebras in
Combinatorics*, arXiv:1409.8356v4](https://arxiv.org/src/1409.8356v4/anc/HopfComb-v58-with-solutions.pdf) (the linked file is the ancillary file
with solutions). Alternatively, it also follows from the Serre reference given
by user218931 in his comment ([Jean-Pierre Serre, *Lie Algebras and Lie
Groups*, Corrected 5th printing, Springer 2006](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-70634-2), Theorem I.IV.4.2). The
former proof is combinatorial, long and intricate (it is the standard argument
using the Hall property of Lyndon words). The latter is shorter and, while in
part still combinatorial (it does pass through Hall families), avoids much of
the work by tricking around with base change and linear algebra. Which of
these proofs you prefer is probably a matter of personal taste.

**3.** Another case where Exercise 7.3.2 is correct is the case when $k$ is a
$\mathbb{Q}$-algebra (that is, $1,2,3,\ldots$ are invertible in $k$). This
follows from Proposition 7.2.8 in Volume I of [Benoit Fresse, *Homotopy of
Operads and Grothendieck-Teichmüller Groups*](http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this complete answer.  It will be certainly also helpful for other readers. I have seen this mistake (that the free Lie algebra embeds into the tensor algebra) not just in Weibel's book, by the way.